# How to use two code into one Excel VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I am trying to create a Hide and Unhide function under one code. But my code does not work.

I simply wants that if rows are hidden then unhide. If rows are not hidden then hide them.

Any help will be appreciated

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Sheets("Current Assets").Range("Table110[Qty.]")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        ElseIf cell.EntireRow.Hidden = True Then
        cell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your logic is wrong - you've got

1. if the value is zero, hide the row
2. otherwise (i.e. if the value is not zero), if the row is hidden, show it.

Does this do more what you want:

```
Sub HideRows()
    Dim cell As Range
    For Each cell In Sheets("Current Assets").Range("Table110[Qty.]")
        If cell.Value = 0 Then
            cell.EntireRow.Hidden = Not cell.EntireRow.Hidden
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Yeah it is, thanks it works perfectly.